# Azure data factory tabular translator expressions documentation

Tags: azure-data-factory

In an ADF pipeline copy action, I need to build a column renaming scheme, and I'm running into lack of documentation on the available tools.

Suppose I've made the following map:

```
{
    "type":"TabularTranslator",
    "mappings":
    [
        {
            "source": { "name": "Property1" },
            "sink": { "name": "Province" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "Property2" },
            "sink": { "name": "Division" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "Property3" },
            "sink": { "name": "County" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "Property4" },
            "sink": { "name": "District" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "Property5" },
            "sink": { "name": "Municipality" }
        }
    ]
}
```

What tools are available to me for referencing other data from the pipeline, like parameters, variables, lookup sets? How can I match source names by expression and construct sink names from the source names? What if I wanted to rename only some columns, and have a catch-all that simply forwards the source name to sink name if none match? Should I be considering other actions besides copy? What are they?

Comment: Main doc is here with some good examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping

Comment: I’m just making one of these custom TabularTranslators where a stored proc creates and returns the json.  Can share more details if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the activities provided within the data factory to build the dynamic mapping JSON. The JSON you have given is the format for dynamic mapping which you will build using iterations, variables (set variable and append variable) conditionals and other activities.
- The following is an example. Let's say I have a file with column names `p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5` and you want to rename these files. If you want to name the files manually, you can directly take a set variable activity to build mapping like below:

```
{
    "type":"TabularTranslator",
    "mappings":
    [
        {
            "source": { "name": "p1" },
            "sink": { "name": "Province" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "p2" },
            "sink": { "name": "Division" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "p3" },
            "sink": { "name": "County" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "p4" },
            "sink": { "name": "District" }
        },
        {
            "source": { "name": "p5" },
            "sink": { "name": "Municipality" }
        }
    ]
}
```

- If you have a file with a column called `column_names` with new column names like below. Look up is used to get the names of new columns.

[image]

- I have used another look up with only one row and deselected first row as header to get header from data file. The file data is as shown below:

[image]

- Then I have used combination of iterations and variable activities to get desired results. The following is the pipeline JSON for the same.

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "new column names",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "cols",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "old column names",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "data",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "new column names",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "old column names",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0,5)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(variables('map'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "map",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "{\"source\": {\"name\": \"@{activity('old column names').output.firstRow[concat('Prop_',item())]}\"},\"sink\": {\"name\": \"@{activity('new column names').output.value[item()]['new_columns']}\"}}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final_mapping",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "{\"type\": \"TabularTranslator\",\"mappings\": @{variables('tp')}}",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "value": "@json(variables('final_mapping'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "current item": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "map": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "final_mapping": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- The following is how the final file looks like:

[image]

- To change the column name only based on your condition, you can simply use if conditional to check. There are also be external ways to build the dynamic mapping JSON as mentioned by **@wbob**.